Why in my submit MUi button in react hook form neither logging on console nor sending data on mongoDB?
I don't understand why my react hook form built with Integration of Controller with various Mui Components such as TextFields Date Picker and Time Pickers two react select components for dropDown menu, while on running clicking Submit Button made with Mui niether I am seeing any kind of log or error on my console nor any kind nor sending my form data on my MongoDB database.
I am using express framework in my backend and MongoDB for my Database on testing the API with Postman the Backend was working fine and POST Request is working fine and data is getting stored in database.
I am using Yup for Validation Purpose and Axios in Client Side for sending data from client side to server.
App.jsx
import React, { useState } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import {
  Box,
  Button,
  Paper,
  Typography,
  Grid,
  Divider,
  AppBar,
  ThemeProvider,
  CssBaseline,
  IconButton,
  TextField,
} from "@mui/material";
import { AdapterDayjs } from "@mui/x-date-pickers/AdapterDayjs";
import { yupResolver } from "@hookform/resolvers/yup";
import validationSchema from "./validation";
import theme from "./Theme";
import { TimePicker } from "@mui/x-date-pickers/TimePicker";
import logo from "./bluescopelogo.png";
import { Controller, useForm } from "react-hook-form";
import Select from "react-select";
import { Transition } from "react-transition-group";
import "./styles.css";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import DropMenu from "./DropMenu";
import { DatePicker, LocalizationProvider } from "@mui/x-date-pickers";
const options = [
  { value: "aadhaar", label: "Aadhaar" },
  { value: "pancard", label: "PAN Card" },
];

const customStyles = {
  control: (provided) => ({
    ...provided,
    fontFamily: "Calibri",
    color: "grey",
    fontSize: 20,
    width: 220,
  }),

  option: (provided) => ({
    ...provided,
    fontFamily: "Calibri",
  }),
};

const CustomSelectController = ({ defaultOption }) => {
  const [selectedOption, setSelectedOption] = useState(defaultOption);
  const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState("");
  const [error, setError] = useState("");

  const handleChange = (selected) => {
    setSelectedOption(selected);
    setInputValue("");
    setError("");
    console.log("Selected option:", selected);
  };

  const handleInputChange = (e) => {
    const { value } = e.target;
    let errorMessage = "";

    if (selectedOption.value === "aadhaar") {
      if (!/^\d{0,12}$/.test(value)) {
        errorMessage = "Please Check your Aadhaar Number.";
      } else if (value.length > 12) {
        errorMessage = "You have exceeded the character limit";
      }
    } else if (selectedOption.value === "pancard") {
      if (!/^[A-Z]{5}[0-9]{4}[A-Z]$/.test(value)) {
        errorMessage = "Please Check your PAN Number.";
      } else if (value.length > 10) {
        errorMessage = "You have exceeded the character limit";
      }
    }
    setInputValue(value);
    setError(errorMessage);
  };

    const handleSubmit = () => {
    if (inputValue.trim() === "") {
      setError("This field can’t be left empty");
    }
  };

  const transitionStyle = {
    entering: { opacity: 0 },
    entered: { opacity: 1 },
    exiting: { opacity: 1 },
    exited: { opacity: 0 },
  };

  return (
    <div
      style={{
        display: "flex",
        alignItems: "left",
        gap: "20px",
        flexDirection: "column",
      }}
    >
      <Select
        value={selectedOption}
        onChange={handleChange}
        placeholder="Identity Proof"
        options={options}
        styles={customStyles}
        menuPosition="fixed"
        menuPortalTarget={document.body}
      />
      <Transition in={!!selectedOption} timeout={100}>
        {(state) => (
          <div
            style={{
              ...transitionStyle[state],
              transition: "opacity 300ms ease-in-out",
              display: "flex",
            }}
          >
            {selectedOption && (
              <TextField
                label={
                  <span>
                    {selectedOption.label}
                    <span style={{ color: "red" }}></span>
                  </span>
                }
                value={inputValue}
                size="small"
                onChange={handleInputChange}
                placeholder=""
                onBlur={handleSubmit}
                error={!!error}
                helperText={error}
                variant="outlined"
                inputProps={{
                  maxLength:
                    selectedOption.value === "aadhaar"
                      ? 12
                      : selectedOption.value === "pancard"
                        ? 10
                        : undefined,
                }}
                sx={{ marginLeft: "0px" }}
              />
            )}
          </div>
        )}
      </Transition>
    </div>
  );
};
CustomSelectController.propTypes = {
  defaultOption: PropTypes.shape({
    value: PropTypes.string,
    label: PropTypes.string,
  }),
};

CustomSelectController.defaultProps = {
  defaultOption: null,
};

const App = () => {
  const { control, handleSubmit } = useForm({
    resolver: yupResolver(validationSchema),
  });

  const onSubmit = async (data) => {
    console.log("Form Data:", data);
    try {
      const response = await axios.post(
        "http://localhost:5000/api/submit",
        data,
      );
      console.log("response:", response.data);
      alert("Submitted Successfully !");
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error submitting Form", error);
      alert("Failed to Submit!");
    }
  };
  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <CssBaseline />
      <div className="gradient-background">
        <Paper
          variant="outlined"
          sx={{
            borderColor: "white",
            backdropFilter: "blur(18px)",
            backgroundColor: "rgba(255,255,250,0.6)",
            borderRadius: 3,
            display: "flexbox",
            width: "100%",
            padding: "70px",
            maxWidth: "1125px",
          }}
        >
          <AppBar
            position="static"
            variant="elevation"
            elevation={0}
            sx={{
              bgcolor: "transparent",
              marginRight: "20px",
              display: "flex",
              alignItems: "right",
            }}
          >
            <Box display="inflex-flex" alignItems="center">
              <img
                src={logo}
                alt="logo"
                style={{
                  height: "59px",
                  width: "89px",
                }}
              />
              <Typography
                variant="h1"
                sx={{
                  alignContent: "left",
                  color: "white",
                  fontSize: "2rem",
                  fontWeight: "normal",
                }}
              >
                Visitor's Gate Pass
              </Typography>
            </Box>
          </AppBar>
          <Divider variant="fullWidth" textAlign="left">
            <Typography
              sx={{
                color: "black",
                fontWeight: "normal",
              }}
            >
              Tabluvian Family Welcome's you!!
            </Typography>
          </Divider>
          <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
            <Grid container spacing={2}>
              <Grid item xs={12} sm={6}>
                <Controller
                  name="vistors_name"
                  control={control}
                  rules={{ required: "Visitor Name is required." }}
                  render={({ field }) => (
                    <TextField
                      {...field}
                      label="Visitor's Name"
                      size="normal"
                      margin="normal"
                      width="normal"
                    />
                  )}
                />
              </Grid>
              <Grid item xs={12}>
                <Controller
                  name="employee_name"
                  control={control}
                  rules={{ required: "Employees Name is required." }}
                  render={({ field }) => (
                    <TextField
                      {...field}
                      label="Employee's Name"
                      size="normal"
                      margin="normal"
                      width="normal"
                    />
                  )}
                />
              </Grid>
              <Grid item xs={6}>
                <Box mt={1}>
                  <CustomSelectController defaultOption={null} />
                </Box>
              </Grid>
              <Grid item xs={16}>
                <Box mt={1}>
                  <DropMenu
                    control={control}
                    name="visitor_type"
                    onChange={(e) => handleRoleChange(e.target.value)}
                  />
                </Box>
              </Grid>
              <Grid item xs={6}>
                <Box mt={1}>
                  <LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDayjs}>
                    <Controller
                      name="date"
                      control={control}
                      render={({
                        field: { onChange, value },
                        fieldState: { error },
                      }) => (
                        <DatePicker
                          label="Date of Visit"
                          disablePast
                          rules={{ required: "Date is required" }}
                          value={value || null}
                          onChange={onChange}
                          renderInput={(params) => (
                            <TextField
                              {...params}
                              error={!!error}
                              helperText={error ? error.message : null}
                            />
                          )}
                        />
                      )}
                    />
                  </LocalizationProvider>
                </Box>
              </Grid>
              <Grid item xs={!2}>
                <Box mt={2}>
                  <LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDayjs}>
                    <Box
                      display="inline-flex"
                      justifyContent="space-between"
                      alignItems="center"
                      gap={8}
                    >
                      <Controller
                        control={control}
                        name="from"
                        render={({ field }) => (
                          <TimePicker
                            {...field}
                            value={field.value || null}
                            label="from"
                            renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} />}
                            onChange={(newValue) => field.onChange(newValue)}
                          />
                        )}
                      />

                      <Controller
                        control={control}
                        name="to"
                        render={({ field }) => (
                          <TimePicker
                            {...field}
                            value={field.value || null}
                            label="to"
                            renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} />}
                            onChange={(newValue) => field.onChange(newValue)}
                          />
                        )}
                      />
                    </Box>
                  </LocalizationProvider>
                </Box>
              </Grid>
              <Grid item xs={12} sm={4} mt={2}>
                <Controller
                  name="serial_number"
                  control={control}
                  render={({
                    field: { onChange, value },
                    fieldState: { error },
                  }) => (
                    <TextField
                      label="Serial No."
                      value={value}
                      onChange={(e) => {
                        const newValue = e.target.value.replace(/[^0-9]/g, "");
                        onChange(newValue);
                      }}
                      error={!!error}
                      helperText={error ? error.message : null}
                      fullWidth
                      variant="outlined"
                      inputProps={{
                        inputMode: "numeric",
                        pattern: "[0-9]*",
                      }}
                    />
                  )}
                />
              </Grid>
              <Grid item xs={18} sm={7}>
                <Controller
                  name="issued_by"
                  control={control}
                  render={({ field, fieldState: { error } }) => (
                    <TextField
                      {...field}
                      label="Issued By"
                      size="normal"
                      error={!!error}
                      helperText={error ? error.message : null}
                      fullWidth
                    />
                  )}
                />
                <Box mt={2}>
                  <Button
                    type="submit"
                    variant="contained"
                    size="small"
                    color="primary"
                  >
                    Submit
                  </Button>
                </Box>
              </Grid>
            </Grid>
          </form>
        </Paper>
      </div>
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
};
export default App;

server.js
const express = require("express");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const cors = require("cors");

const Visitor = require("./Visitor");
const dotenv = require("dotenv");
dotenv.config({ path: "./.env" });

const mongoString = process.env.DATABASE_URL;
mongoose.connect(mongoString);

const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;

app.use(express.json());
app.use(cors());

const db = mongoose.connection;
db.on("error", console.error.bind(console, "connection  error:"));
db.once("open", function () {
  console.log("Database has connected Successfully");
});

app.post("http://localhost:5000/api/submit", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const newVisitor = new Visitor(req.body);
    await newVisitor.save();
    res.status(201).send("Visitor Information Saved Successfully");
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(500).send("Error saving visitor information");
  }
});

app.use((req, res) => {
  res.status(404).send("404 Not Found");
});

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`The Server is Running on port ${port}!!`);
});

validation.jsx
import * as yup from "yup";
let validationSchema = yup
  .object()
  .shape({
    visitors_name: yup.string().trim().required("Visitor Name is Required"),
    employee_name: yup.string().trim().required("Employee Name is Required"),
    date: yup.date().required("Date is required"),
    from: yup.date().required("Start time is required"),
    to: yup.date().required("End time is required"),
    serial_number: yup
      .number()
      .typeError("Serial Number Should be in Numbers")
      .required("Serial Number is required"),
    issued_by: yup.string().required("Name of the issue"),
    visitor_type: yup.string().required("Visitor Type is required"),
    identity_proof: yup.string().required("Identity is Required"),
    identity_number: yup.string().when("identity_proof", {
      is: "aadhaar",
      then: yup
        .string()
        .matches(/^\d{12}$/, "Please Check with your Aadhaar number")
        .required("Aadhaar number is required"),
      otherwise: yup
        .string()
        .matches(
          /^[A-Z]{5}[0-9]{4}[A-Z]$/,
          "Please Check with Your PAN Card Number",
        )
        .required("PAN Number is Required"),
    }),
  })
  .required();
export default validationSchema;

Visitor.js
//mongoose schema
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const visitorSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  visitors_name: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, "Visitor Name is Required"],
  },
  employee_name: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, "Employee Name is Required"],
  },
  date: {
    type: Date,
    required: [true, "Date is required"],
  },
  from: {
    type: Date,
    required: [true, "Start time is required"],
  },
  to: {
    type: Date,
    required: [true, "End time is required"],
  },
  serial_number: {
    type: Number,
    required: [true, "Serial Number is required"],
  },
  issued_by: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, "Name of the issuer is required"],
  },
  visitor_type: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, "Visitor Type is required"],
  },
  identity_proof: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, "Identity Proof is Required"],
  },
  identity_number: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, "Identity Number is Required"],
    validate: {
      validator: function (v) {
        if (this.identity_proof === "aadhaar") {
          return /^\d{12}$/.test(v);
        } else {
          return /^[A-Z]{5}[0-9]{4}[A-Z]$/.test(v);
        }
      },
      message: (props) => {
        if (
          props.path === "identity_number" &&
          props.instance.identity_proof === "aadhaar"
        ) {
          return "Please Check your Aadhar number";
        } else {
          return "Please Check your PAN Card Number";
        }
      },
    },
  },
});

const Visitor = mongoose.model("Visitor", visitorSchema);
module.exports = Visitor;

Earlier on clicking Submit Button I was getting a log on Console.
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: branch is not a function
    at _Condition.fn (yup.js?v=a2fc6f29:429:51)
    at _Condition.resolve (yup.js?v=a2fc6f29:443:23)
    at yup.js?v=a2fc6f29:804:71
    at Array.reduce (<anonymous>)
    at StringSchema.resolve (yup.js?v=a2fc6f29:804:27)
    at ObjectSchema._cast (yup.js?v=a2fc6f29:1903:23)
    at ObjectSchema._validate (yup.js?v=a2fc6f29:856:20)
    at ObjectSchema._validate (yup.js?v=a2fc6f29:1942:11)
    at yup.js?v=a2fc6f29:965:52
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)Understand this error

For which I Downgrade my yup from 1.4 to 0.32.11 but after doing so the following problem that is mentioned in title is happening that submit button is neither showing any log on console nor uploading data on database.
I want when I click Submit button the data should go to my database.

I think that you may be running into this https://github.com/jquense/yup/issues/2020
The yup official team has documented the expected parameter types for then / for clauses and noted it in their migration guide to v1
https://github.com/jquense/yup/issues/1906
I don't know about a version as old as .32.11, but I think it would be reasonable from the error you are seeing to update to the latest release (1.4) as of this writing and to write your .then / .to arguments to fit the expected type such that yup can resolve them correctly.
quote from their migration guide: "tl;dr; use functions for then/otherwise conditions. convert .when({ to: true, then: yup.string().required() }) to .when({ to: true, then: schema => schema.required() })"
